# SPOJ COINS DP and Recursive Approach

Tags: c, algorithm, segmentation-fault, dynamic-programming

I have recently started solving DP problem and I came across COINS. I tried to solve it using DP with memoization and it works fine if I use int array(I guess).
Here is my approach(few modifications left):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int dp[100000];
long long max(long x, long y)
{
   if (x > y)
      return x;
   else
      return y;
}
int main()
{
    int n,i;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    dp[0]=0;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        dp[i]=max(i,dp[i/2] + dp[i/3] + dp[i/4]);
    }
    printf("%d\n",dp[n]);

    return 0;
}
```

But I don't understand as soon as I use long long array I get SIGSEGV.
I searched and there seems to be a recursive solution that I am not understanding.
Can someone help me out here?

Comment: The limits say `n<=10e9`, array size of which will always result in memory overflow and hence, SIGSEGV. It does not matter what is the type of your dp-array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limits say `n<=10e9`, array size of which will always result in memory overflow and hence, `SIGSEGV`. It does not matter what is the type of your dp-array.

There are yet other errors in your code. Firstly, there are test-cases, which you have to read till EOF. Secondly, since the limits are `10e9`, you are looping `n` times !! Surely TLE.

Now, for the recursive solution, using memoization:

Firstly, save the answer values till `10e6` in the array. Will help save time. It can be done as:

```
long long dp[1000000] = {0};
for(int i = 1; i < 1000000; i++){
    dp[i] = max(i, dp[i/2] + dp[i/3] + dp[i/4]);
}
```

Now, for any input `n`, find the solution as,

```
ans = coins(n);
```

Implement `coins` function as:

```
long long coins(long long n){
    if (n < 1000000)
        return dp[n];
    return coins(n/2) + coins(n/3) + coins(n/4);
}
```

> Why this recursive solution works:

It is very obvious that answer for all `n >= 12` will be `ans[n/2] + ans[n/3] + ans[n/4]`, so for `n > 10e6`, that is returned.

The base condition for the recursion is just to save time. You can also return it for `0`, but then then you will have to take care of corner cases. (You get my point there)

Exact code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
long long dp[1000000] = {0};

long long max(long long a, long long b){
    return a>b?a:b;
}

long long coins(long long n){
    if (n < 1000000)
        return dp[n];
    return coins(n/2) + coins(n/3) + coins(n/4);
}

int main(){
for(long long i = 1; i < 1000000; i++){
    dp[i] = max(i, dp[i/2] + dp[i/3] + dp[i/4]);
}
long long n;
while(scanf("%lld",&n) != EOF){
    printf("%lld\n", coins(n));
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Man! That helped a LOT! I wonder where I can contact you or see your solutions just for reference..

Comment: Also, Is this a common trick to follow the recursion approach when n<=10e9? My recursion concepts are a bit weak.

Comment: Yeah...this reduces time manifold. You must choose the base case of recursion in such a way, always, so that the depth of recursion is minimized. This is because, recursion is a double edged sword. As much as it helps reducing the code length, if recursion stack goes too deep, it causes stack-overflow, which also results in SIGSEGV. (Try it yourself, in any graph problem in spoj only that solves using DFS and has good limits for (E,V), try it with recursion, will cause SO. When you implement the same logic of DFS iteratively, it will run easily)

Comment: Also, avoid using recursion if possible. Building recursion stack in system memory is also an expensive process, both in time and memory.

Comment: As far as contacting me is concerned, here on SO is ok anytime. I go through some posts atleast once a day, where I can help. You can also find me on FB :)